# Why is $f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f_{n-1}(t)\sin(x-t)dt $ uniformly convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

The function of the sequence defined on the $\mathbb{R}$ by  $f_n(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f_{n-1}(t)\sin(x-t)dt $, $n\geq 2$, plus $f_1(x) = \cos x$.

The first step to show the uniform convergence, I'm trying the find the limit function.

Let the  $f(x)$ be the limit function of the sequence. (Under the hypothesis that $f_n$ is u.c to $f$ )

Then $f(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f(t)\sin(x-t)dt =\int_{x}^{x+1}f(u-x)\sin u du $ by putting the $u =x -t$

The only thing left to do is just find the $f(x)$. But From this step, I was totally stuck for finding the $f$.

What should I do next?

Comment: *Hint.* We have $\displaystyle C = \max_{[-1,1]} \, \lvert \sin x \rvert<1$. Can you then show that $$\|f_n| \leq C \|f_{n-1}\|, \quad\text{where}\quad \|f\|=\sup_{[0,1]}|f|\quad ?$$

Comment: @SangchulLee, What a Good hint! I'll try it again.  :)

Comment: @SangchulLee, I tried that again although your hint. I failed to solve that.  Would you please give me more hints for me ?

Comment: @OliverDiaz, As far as I understand you estimate $\int_0^1 |\sin (x-t)| dt \leq \sup_{x\in[-1,1]}|\sin(x)|$. But this is not true. This integral for $x=\pi/2+0.5$ gives $\approx 0.95 $ when $\sin(1) \approx 0.84$. Do I understand something wrong?

Comment: But in the question, it is stated explicitly that we are interested in convergence over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: It is your statement that those are functions from $C([0,1])$. In the question, it is written: "defined on $\mathbb{R}$". And there is no need to be funny and try $x=1000$, it is obvious that the maximum is in $x=\pi/2+0.5$.

Comment: @NikolayEbel: Granted, the functions $f_n$ are defined on all the real line; however, the only values of the argument that matter are those in $[0,1]$, because that is where you are integrating over to defined the next member of the sequence. It is irrelevant what happens outside $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**straightforward method**

Let's look at the sequence:
$$
f_1=\cos(x), \ f_2=\frac{1}{4}(\cos(2-x)-\cos(x)+2\sin(x)), \ f_3=-\frac{1}{4}\cos^2(1)\cos(x)
$$
From $f_3$ the sequence repeats itself with the factor $-\frac{1}{4}\cos^2(1)$ which is smaller than $1$ (by absolute value). Absolute values of the first two functions are bounded over $\mathbb{R}$ with some positive $A$. Thus we have
$$
\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} f_n<(\frac{1}{4}\cos^2(1))^k A, \ n > 2k
$$
Thus we have a uniform limit $f=0$.

**(similar to) prove with the hint**

$$
\|f_n\|=\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f_n(x)|=\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |\int_0^1 f_{n-1}(t)\sin(x-t) dt |\leq \\
\leq\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}} \int_0^1 |f_{n-1}(t)\sin(x-t)| dt\leq\|f_{n-1}\|\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\int_0^1|\sin(x-t)|dt =\\
\|f_{n-1}\|\max_{x\in \mathbb{R}}\int_x^{x+1}|\sin(t)|dt 
$$
The integral is obviously $<1-\delta$ for some $\delta\in(0,1)$. Thus we have
$$
\|f_n\|\leq \|f_{n-1}\|(1-\delta).
$$

Answer (score 2):

Define the map $A:C([0,1])\rightarrow C([0,1])$ as
$$ Af(x)=\int^1_0 f(t)\sin(x-t)\,dt,\qquad 0\leq x\leq 1$$

For any $f,g\in C([0,1])$

$$|Af(x)-Ag(x)|\leq \int^1_0 |f(t)-g(t)||\sin(x-t)|\,dx\leq\sin(1)\|f-g\|_u$$
where $\|\;\|_u$ is the uniform norm on $C([0,1])$. A direct application of the Banach fixed point theorem there is a unique fixed point $f_*\in C([0,1])$ and that for any $f_0\in C([0,1]$
$f_n=Af_{n-1}$ converges (in the uniform norm) to $f_*$.

Further inspection of $A$ shows that $f(t)\equiv0$ is a fixed point of $A$; hence the only one. To summarize: for any $f_0\in C([0,1])$
$f_n=Af_{n-1}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ uniformly.

*Observation:* As mention in several comments, one can do without a full application of the Banach fixed point theorem.  For any $f_0\in C([0,1])$
$$\|Af_0\|_u\leq \sin1\|f\|_u$$
Setting $A^{\circ n}=A\circ\ldots \circ A$ $n$-times yields
$$\|A^{\circ n}\|_u\leq (\sin 1)^n\|f\|_u\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
(in the OP's notation, $f_n=A^{\circ n}f_0$)

Comment: Also the zero function is fixed and thus $f_*$ is the zero function :)

Comment: (+1) Also, without the use of the full use Banac's fixed point theorem one gets $\|Af\|_\leq\sin(1)\|f\|_u$ and so $\|A^{\circ n}f\|_n\leq(\sin^n1)\|f\|_u\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ for any $f\in C([0,1])$.